# How can we change the Flutter NavigationRail item hover color and shape?

Tags: flutter

In my flutter TV project, I'm using NavigationRail widget as side bar, I want to change the default hover color, however I did not find that option in the NavigationRail widget properties.

I want to:

1. Change the hover color of side item from grey to lightblue
2. Change the hover shape from rounded rectangle to rectangle

[image]

Sample Dartpad code [dartpad sample code](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [NavigationRail].

void main() => runApp(const NavigationRailExampleApp());

class NavigationRailExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationRailExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          sliderTheme: const SliderThemeData(
              showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.always,
              activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
              thumbColor: Colors.white,
              valueIndicatorColor: Colors.red),
          listTileTheme: const ListTileThemeData(
              iconColor: Colors.white, textColor: Colors.white),
          appBarTheme:
              AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900, elevation: 0),
          applyElevationOverlayColor: true,
          focusColor: Colors.grey,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
          navigationRailTheme: NavigationRailThemeData(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
              unselectedLabelTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              selectedLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow.shade700),
              unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
              selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.yellow),
              indicatorColor: Colors.grey.shade200),
          elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
            style: ButtonStyle(
                elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(0),
                backgroundColor:
                    MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey.shade900),
                shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                    Colors.grey.shade700)), // Here Im having the error
          )),
      home: NavRailExample(),
    );
  }
}

class NavRailExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavRailExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<NavRailExample> createState() => _NavRailExampleState();
}

class _NavRailExampleState extends State<NavRailExample> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  NavigationRailLabelType labelType = NavigationRailLabelType.all;
  bool showLeading = false;
  bool showTrailing = false;
  double groupAlignment = -1.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          NavigationRail(
            extended: true,
            groupAlignment: groupAlignment,
            labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.none,
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
            leading: showLeading
                ? FloatingActionButton(
                    elevation: 0,
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Add your onPressed code here!
                    },
                    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                  )
                : const SizedBox(),
            trailing: showTrailing
                ? IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Add your onPressed code here!
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.more_horiz_rounded),
                  )
                : const SizedBox(),
            destinations: const <NavigationRailDestination>[
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                label: Text('First'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.book),
                label: Text('Second'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.star_border),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.star),
                label: Text('Third'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
          // This is the main content.
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('selectedIndex: $_selectedIndex'),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text('Label type: ${labelType.name}'),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                OverflowBar(
                  spacing: 10.0,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          labelType = NavigationRailLabelType.none;
                        });
                      },
                      child: const Text('None'),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          labelType = NavigationRailLabelType.selected;
                        });
                      },
                      child: const Text('Selected'),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          labelType = NavigationRailLabelType.all;
                        });
                      },
                      child: const Text('All'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text('Group alignment: $groupAlignment'),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                OverflowBar(
                  spacing: 10.0,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          groupAlignment = -1.0;
                        });
                      },
                      child: const Text('Top'),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          groupAlignment = 0.0;
                        });
                      },
                      child: const Text('Center'),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          groupAlignment = 1.0;
                        });
                      },
                      child: const Text('Bottom'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                OverflowBar(
                  spacing: 10.0,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          showLeading = !showLeading;
                        });
                      },
                      child:
                          Text(showLeading ? 'Hide Leading' : 'Show Leading'),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          showTrailing = !showTrailing;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                          showTrailing ? 'Hide Trailing' : 'Show Trailing'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code which you tried. If it is possible please provide a small replicable example on dartpad.dev

Comment: updated question with code you can paste here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html

Comment: updated code >> https://dartpad.dev/?id=1d0f394697cbf864ab2b478a739cbb0a